# Problema ao executar um script no php?

Tags: php, ubuntu

criei um script para executar um programa automaticamente, ele está correto pois em linha de comando no ubuntu ele executa através do comando:

```
/var/www/html/trabalhoTCC/view/needle.sh /var/www/html/trabalhoTCC/emboss/aaindexextract/alvos.txt  /var/www/html/trabalhoTCC/emboss/aaindexextract/modelos.txt
```

onde needle.sh é meu script que recebe como parâmetro os arquivos al.txt e mod.txt.

No terminal do ubuntu eu consigo executar esse comando e ter o arquivo de saída dele, mas ao executar esse comando no php :

```
shell_exec('/var/www/html/trabalhoTCC/view/needle.sh /var/www/html/trabalhoTCC/emboss/aaindexextract/alvos.txt /var/www/html/trabalhoTCC/emboss/aaindexextract/modelos.txt');
```

não obtenho a saída, alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Olha esse parte que você colocou ela esta desse jeito no script ? porque no final do comando tem uma Aspa simples, retira ela

Comment: Outra coisa, tente colocar tudo em uma linha só

Comment: não tem a aspas não, coloquei errado aqui. .

Comment: Certo, agora no script coloca tudo em uma linha só: **shell_exec('/var/www/html/trabalho/view/needle.sh /var/www/html/trabalho/view/emboss/needle/al.txt /var/www/html/trabalho/view/emboss/needle/mod.txt');**

Comment: arrumei aqui havia colocado errado também,  desse jeito que está e não obtenho saída.

Comment: Certo, verifica a permissão para executar o arquivo needle.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica se as funções `exec()` e `shell_exec()` estão habilitadas no PHP.

**Solução**

O arquivo / diretório ( pasta ) não havia permissão suficiente, para que o arquivo pudesse ser executado.

Foi dada a permissão necessária utilizando o comando **chmod**.

Comment: as funções estão habilitadas pois cheguei a executar o comando chmod com o shell_exec e ele funcionou.

Comment: Você pode redirecionar os erros do shell com `2>&1` no final do seu script para saber o que está dando errado.

Comment: esta me retornando esse erro Gap opening penalty [10.0]: Gap extension penalty [0.5]: Output alignment [hba_human.needle]: Warning: Failed to open output file 'hba_human.needle' error:13 'Permission denied' Error: Unable to open alignment file 'hba_human.needle' Output alignment [hba_human.needle]: , que nao possui permisao parar abrir o arquivo de saida, mas no ubuntu ao executar o mesmo script ele funciona, algo do php?

Comment: Dê permissão de execução ao arquivo para que ele possa ser executado como `chmod 777 /var/www/html/trabalhoTCC/view/needle.sh`. Atenção: esse é um exemplo drástico que dá todas as permissões para todo mundo. Dá uma olhada na documentação do [**EMBOSS sobre gaps**](http://structure.usc.edu/emboss/needle.html)

Comment: descobri o erro a pasta view que coloquei o script para testar estava sem permissão para a saída com isso a saída não podia ser salva nessa pasta, muito obrigado.

Comment: @user86792 atualiza a resposta de acordo com a solução do problema

Comment: @WMSouza Acharia mais justo que você escrevesse a resposta e que a sua resposta fosse marcada como correta. Acabei de ver que você deu a dica de verificar as permissões 14 minutos antes de mim. EU só coloquei uma resposta aqui porque não podia comentar. (Reputação com menos de 50 pontos)

Comment: Sem problemas, estamos aqui pra ajudar, pode editar.